# Saving usernames of selected tableview rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to save all the usernames corresponding to each row in the tableView. I have the below code which seems to only save the user in the first row. Not sure what is wrong or how I can fix it.

```
var selectedIndexPathArray = [IndexPath?]() (outside of functions)


@IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
 ...
    guard let selectedIndexPathArray = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
        return
    }
    for user in selectedIndexPathArray {
        selectedUsers.append(followingKeys[user])
    }
    selectedUsers.append(User.current.username)
}


extension SendToPopOverViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    ...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPathArray = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
    }
```

I also have this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't want `selectedIndexPathArray` since `UITableView` keeps track of selected index paths. Second, in your `sendTapped(_:)` function, you should use `indexPathsForSelectedRows` instead of `indexPathForSelectedRow` in your `guard let` statement. Assuming that `followingKeys` is an array of usernames, the code should be as follows:

```
guard let selectedIndexPathArray = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
    return
}
for indexPath in selectedIndexPathArray {
    selectedUsers.append(followingKeys[indexPath.row])
}
selectedUsers.append(User.current.username)
```

Comment: Ok so I should delete the function under extensions and the var selectedIndexPathArray = [IndexPath?]()? I am also getting this error for the for loop part but followingKeys is an array of users..."Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'IndexPath' "

Comment: From the code you posted, you do seem to need it. So, yes.

Comment: You seem to be using `followingKeys[indexPath]` instead of `followingKeys[indexPath.row]` now, but it will be nice if you could post both your `followingKeys` array declaration and your updated code.

Comment: you're right I changed it to followingKeys[user.row] thank you!!